# How to get access token on implict flow in spring security oauth 2

Tags: oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

How to get access token as json response in implicit call.What custom filter do I need to add in spring-servlet ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to add any custom filter to get an access_token in the implicit flow. In the spring security oauth's "oauth:authorization-server" bean configurtion you need to include the type's of flow that your auth server will be accepting. You can refer to a sample application configuration I was playing around [here.](https://github.com/nareshbafna/oauth2/blob/master/sparklr/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml)